# Copy files using script to a network share

Tags: sql-server-agent

Is there a simple script I can use to copy files in a particular folder to a network share? This is for use with SQL Server Agent so I can run it as a step after backups.

Thanks

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking, but I blogged something very similar just today: http://spaghettidba.com/2013/02/08/manual-log-shipping-with-powershell/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is (part of) a script that I use to "archive" files that were processed by SQL Server. I actually mapped the network drive instead of moving to a UNC because it was just more stable.

A few things to note:

- The service account under which the SQL Agent runs must have
  permissions on both the source and the target (I'm assuming the
  target would be the one you'd really need to check, unless the Agent
  account can't delete from the local store).
- This script `MOVE`s the files. If you want to copy them, then I'd recommend looking into replacing the command in the last step with [`XCOPY`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true)

```
    EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', 
       @type=N'LOCAL',@name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'

    IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

    END

    DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
    EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'File Mover', 
            @enabled=1, 
            @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
            @notify_level_email=2, 
            @notify_level_netsend=0, 
            @notify_level_page=0, 
            @delete_level=0, 
            @description=N'No description available.', 
            @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
            @owner_login_name=N'[username]', 
            @notify_email_operator_name=N'alertteam', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT

    EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'Archive Files', 
            @step_id=3, 
            @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
            @on_success_action=1, 
            @on_success_step_id=0, 
            @on_fail_action=2, 
            @on_fail_step_id=0, 
            @retry_attempts=0, 
            @retry_interval=0, 
            @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'CmdExec', 
            @command=N'move \source\path\*.csv \dest\path
    ', 
            @flags=0
```

Comment: swasheck's answer will create you a new job with a copy step inside. If you just want to add a new step to an existing backup job then take the last part (with sp_add_jobstep), but be sure to add it in the context of the already existing backup job.

Comment: good point. i missed the "backup" part